# Looping through JSON response objects

Tags: javascript, json, progressive-web-apps

Please, I want to loop over this json response from an API, I keep getting undefined, when I log it to the console.

```
   {
              "results": {
                  "AF": {
                      "alpha3": "AFG",
                      "currencyId": "AFN",
                      "currencyName": "Afghan afghani",
                      "currencySymbol": "؋",
                      "id": "AF",
                      "name": "Afghanistan"
                  },
                  "AI": {
                      "alpha3": "AIA",
                      "currencyId": "XCD",
                      "currencyName": "East Caribbean dollar",
                      "currencySymbol": "$",
                      "id": "AI",
                      "name": "Anguilla"
                  },
                  "AU": {
                      "alpha3": "AUS",
                      "currencyId": "AUD",
                      "currencyName": "Australian dollar",
                      "currencySymbol": "$",
                      "id": "AU",
                      "name": "Australia"
                  }
                }
            }
```

this is my code:

```js
async function currency() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/currencies`);
    const json = await response.json();
    //console.log(json.results);
    for (key in json.results) {
    
        for(x in key){
            console.log(x)
        }

    
    }
    
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong

Comment: looks like inner loop should be for(x in json.results[key])...

Comment: does my solution not work or something?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the minor edit below should be sufficient... Let me know if it works.

```
async function currency() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/currencies`);
    const json = await response.json();
    //console.log(json.results);
    for (key in json.results) {

       for(x in json.results[key]){
           console.log(json.results[key][x])
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: @OgbonnaVitalis NP!

Comment: nice.... async/await could be used like this too!!! I thought it is mandatory to use `then`.

Comment: @AmitKumar i know nothing about `async-await` but i imagine the script can't do anything with `json` until both of the statements with the `await` keyword are resolved

Answer (score 0):

Convert your json obj  to Map Object  or Set Object  . Then u can try loop over it

> var myMap = new Map();
>   myMap.set(jsonResp);

for (let data of myMap.keys()) { console.log(data); }

[Check here for more information](https://javascript.info/map-set-weakmap-weakset)

And.  [More details here](http://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not frequent user of async/await but i think the correct way would be,

```
async function currency() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/currencies`);
    const json = await response.json();  
    return json;      
}
currency().then(data=>{
    console.log(data);
});
```